# Android - Google Map - Customized Image on google map - Zoom out image

Tags: android, image, google-maps, zooming

I am trying to mark my University buildings in Google Maps with markers for each building using Android. I have placed images for each building on the GoogleMaps. Problem is when I zoom out maps, images that I have placed on it doesn't zoom out. So after zooming out it looks very cluttered. Please help with ideas. Thanks.

Comment: Hey buddy ..have you find the solution ..please tell me Having same issue?